# distance between a set of points-without using loop

Tags: matlab

I need to calculate the distance between a set of N points. All points are 2-d vectors.
`distance_between_points = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)`

Comment: Please be explicit. How do you store your points? What have you tried? Did Google really not turn up any results?

Comment: Didn't I answer this in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330614/using-loop-for-an-equation-with-two-indices#comment122549572_69330614) of your previous question?